# apply method on element name which is stored in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i have store element id in a variable so how can i apply any method like show() , hide() on it .
 say "var a" has it name ,now how to say hide() this element ??

Thanks ,

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
 $("#"+ a).hide();
```

where `a` holds the `id`

[ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in jquery:

```
$('#'+your_id).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide it to the jquery Object as you would with a plain string.

```
var id = "#yourid";
$(id).hide();

// or

var id = "yourid";
$("#"+id).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#elementId").hide();
```

But you could use this way

```
var eleId = "elementId";
$("#"+eleId).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache the id in variable and use it.

```
 var element = $("#"+holder);

 element.hide();
 element.show();
```

Comment: While it's a good idea, `id` is an odd choice of name for the variable considering it's not an ID.